# PHP Array to Json Object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I need to convert a PHP array to JSON but I don't get what I expect.
I want it to be an object that I can navigate easily with a numeric index.
Here's an example code:

```
$json = array();
$ip = "192.168.0.1";
$port = "2016";
array_push($json, ["ip" => $ip, "port" => $port]);
$json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
// ----- json_decode($json)["ip"] should be "192.168.0.1" ----
echo $json;
```

This is what I get

```
[  
   [  
      "ip" => "192.168.0.1",
      "port" => "2016"
   ]
]
```

But I want to get an object instead of array:

```
{  
   "0": {  
      "ip": "192.168.0.1",
      "port": "2016"
   }
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want the outer array to become a JSON object? If it's only got numeric keys, an array delivers the same information in slightly less space and is easier to work with on the JS side of things (you can use `Array::forEach` and `Array::map` for example).

Comment: @00Davo Thanks, because I thought it was easier to handle it when it's an object hhh, and I use it mostly on server-side (PHP) only :)   P.S. Upvoted

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want to `json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`.

The [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) flag, as the name implies, forces the json output to be an object, even when it otherwise would normally be represented as an array.

You can also eliminate the use of `array_push` for some slightly cleaner code:

```
$json[] = ['ip' => $ip, 'port' => $port];
```

Comment: Thanks but this is what I get: {
    "0": {
        "0": "ip => 192.168.0.1",
        "1": "port => 2016"
    }
}

Comment: Your strings are not quite on the right place in your `array_push`. Try `array_push($json, ["ip" => $ip, "port" => $port]);`

Comment: `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` solve my issue, thanks

Answer (score 10):

just use only

```
$response=array();
$response["0"]=array("ip"     => "192.168.0.1",
                     "port"   => "2016");
$json=json_encode($response,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 5):

To get array with objects you can create stdClass() instead of array for inner items like below;

```
<?PHP

    $json = array();
    $itemObject = new stdClass();
    $itemObject->ip = "192.168.0.1";
    $itemObject->port = 2016;

    array_push($json, $itemObject);
    $json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo $json;

?>
```

A working example http://ideone.com/1QUOm6

Comment: imo this is the only proper answer. Especially if you want an object inside of an array.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get an object and not just a json string try:

```
$json = json_decode(json_encode($yourArray));
```

If you want to jsonise the nested arrays as well do:

```
$json =json_decode(json_encode($yourArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case if you want to access your objectivitized json whole data OR a specific key value:

**PHP SIDE**

```
 $json = json_encode($yourdata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**JS SIDE**

```
 var json = <?=$json?>;
 console.log(json);            // {ip:"192.168.0.1", port:"2016"}
 console.log(json['ip']);      // 192.168.0.1
 console.log(json['port']);    // 2016
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ip   = "192.168.0.1";
$port = "2016";
$json = array("response" => array("ip" => $ip, "port" => $port)); 
//IF U NEED AS JSON OBJECT
$json = [array("ip" => $ip, "port" => $port)]; //IF U NEED AS JSON ARRAY
$json = json_encode($json);
echo $json;
```