# php - convert mysql data into json object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I using codeigniter. I want to retrive data from database and convert it into JSON object not JSON array.I'm using following code

```
    public function json()
 {
        $content = $this->db->get('todolist'); //todolist table name
        $data = $content->result_array();
        echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

Above code is converting database into JSON array.
Output

```
[{"todo_id":"1","todo_content":"Homework","date":"2016-05-05","iscomplete":null,"imagelink":"Lighthouse.jpg"},{"todo_id":"2","todo_content":"exam","date":"2015-04-21","iscomplete":null,"imagelink":"Desert.jpg"},{"todo_id":"3","todo_content":"Lab report","date":"2014-08-29","iscomplete":null,"imagelink":"FB_IMG_14700753538617403.jpg"}]
```

What will be best way to convert it into JSON object

Comment: Do you want the keys of the object to be numerical? Why do you even want to force an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) see the example below.

```
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 4):

Sangam try to understand the concept, check the following line:

```
$data = $content->result_array();    // $data is an array
echo json_encode($data);             // here you are converting it into an json object
```

Your `$data` array contains more than one index in it that's why the json object is having multiple `{}` inside `[]`;

Comment: Thumbs up! This is what really happening with you. You need to iterate that object by javascript if you want the values to process.

Answer (score 2):

You want to `json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`.

The  [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](http://www.php.net/json_encode) flag, as the name implies, forces the json output to be an object, even when it otherwise would normally be represented as an array.

Refer: [PHP Array to Json Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099682/php-array-to-json-object)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're only getting one row back from your query.

change

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

to

```
echo json_encode($data[0]);
```