# php reverse iteration over nested array to create node/edge json

Tags: php, arrays, json

In my array `$data` I am trying to convert it into a json with three arrays inside: `nodes`, `edges`, `categorys`.

`categorys`: will have the first element names as the general categories.

`nodes`: will have each of the subcategories, and the number of items it has inside it, that will go the property "Nbdoc".

`edges`: will be the links between the nodes. For example, `subcategory1` and `subcategory3` have one item in common "1001", so the `size` will be one. Either of `subcategory3` or`subcategory1` could be as the source, or could be as the target, it doesn't matter the order.

the `id` property is just a unique id starting from 1 in incremental order. We attribute a unique id for each node and also each edge (link).

sample data:

```
Array
(
    [mycategory1] => Array
        (
            [subcategory1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1001
                    [1] => 1002
                    [2] => 1003
                )

            [subcategory2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1004
                    [1] => 1005
                    [2] => 1006
                    [3] => 1007
                    [4] => 1008                    
                )

            [subcategory3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1008
                    [1] => 1001
                    [2] => 1005
                    [3] => 1006
               )
          )

    [mycategory2] => Array
        (
            [subcategory4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1008
                    [1] => 1005
                    [2] => 1003
               )
          )
)
```

what I currently have:

```
<?php

protected function myfunction()
    {

        $data = somefunction(...);
        $nodes = array();
        $categorys = array();
        $edges = array();
        $nodesArray = array();
        $nodeId = 1;
        $edgeId = 1;
        $json = array();

        foreach ($data as $category => $value) {
            $categorys[] = array('category' => $category, 'icon' => null);
            print_r($categorys);

            foreach ($value as $node => $nodeValue) {
                $nodesArray[$nodeId] = $nodeValue;
                print_r($nodeId);
                die();
                $nodes[] = array('name' => $node, 'category' => $category, 'id' => $nodeId, 'NbDoc' => count($nodeValue));
                for ($i = 1; $i < $nodeId; $i++) {
                    $count = array_count_values(array_merge($nodesArray[$i], $nodesArray[$nodeId]));
                    $size = 0;
                    foreach ($count as $key => $edgeSize) {
                        if ($edgeSize > 1) {
                            $size++;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($size > 0) {
                        $edges[] = array('target' => $nodeId, 'source' => $i, 'id' => $edgeId, 'size' => $size);
                        $edgeId++;
                    }
                }

                $nodeId++;

            }
        }
        $json['categorys'] = $categorys;
        $json['nodes'] = $nodes;
        $json['edges'] = $edges;

        return $json;
    }
```

the desired json output:

```
{
    "categorys": [
        {
            "category": "mycategory1",
            "icon": null
        },
        {
            "category": "mycategory2",
            "icon": null
        }           
    ],
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "subcategory1",
            "category": "mycategory1",
            "id": 1,
            "NbDoc": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "subcategory2",
            "category": "mycategory1",
            "id": 2,
            "NbDoc": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "subcategory3",
            "category": "mycategory1",
            "id": 3,
            "NbDoc": 4
        },
        {
            "name": "subcategory4",
            "category": "mycategory2",
            "id": 4,
            "NbDoc": 3
        }       
    ],
    "edges": [
        {
            "target": 3,
            "source": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "target": 4,
            "source": 1,
            "id": 2,
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "target": 3,
            "source": 2,
            "id": 3,
            "size": 3
        },
        {
            "target": 4,
            "source": 2,
            "id": 4,
            "size": 2
        },
        {
            "target": 4,
            "source": 3,
            "id": 5,
            "size": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Array to Json Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099682/php-array-to-json-object)

Comment: is that a homework :D ?