# Encoding JSON with PHP from database table data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to be able to encode JSON into a specific format so that it can be used with another script that I have created. I am able to encode it with PHP  into JSON but need to be able to push these encoded JSON sets to a 'named' array.

At the moment I am getting this

```
{
    "ann_date":"14\/12\/2017",
    "ann_title":"Return Dates",
    "ann_content":"Have a good break. The course timetable resumes on Wednesday 3rd January 2018",
    "tutor":"John Smith"
}
```

From this code

```
class AnnData {
    public $ann_date = "";
    public $ann_title = "";
    public $ann_content = "";
    public $tutor = "";
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ann_date = $row['ann_date'];
    $ann_title = $row['ann_title'];
    $ann_content = $row['ann_content'];
    $tutor = $row['tutor'];

    $annData = new AnnData();
    $annData->ann_date =  $ann_date;
    $annData->ann_title  = $ann_title;
    $annData->ann_content  = $ann_content;
    $annData->tutor  = $tutor;

    $annQ = json_encode($annData);
```

But need it to look like this

```
{
"announcements":[{
    "ann_date":"14\/12\/2017",
    "ann_title":"Return Dates",
    "ann_content":"Have a good break. The course timetable resumes on Wednesday 3rd January 2018",
   "tutor":"John Smith"}]
}
```

Comment: This thread will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099682/php-array-to-json-object Hope this helps!

Comment: `$result['announcements'][] = $annData`… You simply need to build the actual data structure you want…

Comment: Try `$result = array(); $result['announcements'] = $annData; $annQ = json_encode($result);`, is it the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an associative array and then encode it:

```
$annData = new AnnData();
...
$out = array('announcements' => array($annData));
$outJson = json_encode($out);
```

Comment: With this code I need to be able to add more JSON object to the array, at the moment it is creating an array for each of the JSON objects. Sorry bit of a novice with PHP.

Comment: $announcements = array();

for (...) {

array_push($announcements, $object);

}

$outJson = json_encode(array('announcements' => $announcements));

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a lot by getting the correct columns from your database (only the 4 your need) and fetching all rows at once:

```
$annQ = json_encode([
    'announcements' => mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC),
]);
```

This replaces all the code you have posted.

An associative array will be stored in the string as an object so you don't need that class either if you are not going to use it anywhere else.

Comment: that would be true if the db schema has no other fields in the said table.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg That's why I mentioned that the OP needs to get the correct columns from the database :-)

Comment: duh ... sorry about the noise ;)

Comment: I'm getting back that fetch_all is undefined, suspect its because of PHP version, any other way of doing this?

Comment: @saunders07 That sounds unlikely, it is available for php 5.3+. What version are you on?